# Is atmospheric pressure balanced on an object as it moves?

Tags: classical-mechanics, pressure, atmospheric-science, drag, air

Consider a box sliding along a friction-less floor at a constant velocity.

Now typically atmospheric pressure is 14.7 psi on all surfaces of the object. But if it is moving at a constant velocity, wouldn't there be a void in the air on the backside as it displaces the air? So wouldn't the box feel that 14.7psi on the side plowing into the air, slowing it down?

I know this doesn't happen though. We can show experimentally work in=work out, and the air drag and such are negligible.

So how is the air on the backside staying in balance? this is probably a dumb question i am missing something easy for sure.

Answer (score 2):

If a body is moving very slowly, the air can easily move around it, resulting in the negligible drag terms.  In practice, that void gets filled by air near the void, and the atmosphere takes the least effort required to populate the empty space.  When you move the box, the air in front of the box is displaced, creating a *slightly* higher pressure region, which induces a flow towards the back of the box with its *slightly* lower pressure.  We're talking tiny fractions of a psi, not the full 14.7psi of atmospheric pressure.  Go slow enough, and the pressures will be extremely low.  You will get the result you found: we can neglect drag and just say work-in = work-out

Increase the speed, and we know this process becomes non-negligible.  It's a major design factor for cars and airplanes.

If you want to feel what it would be like if the air did not flow like this, find a syringe without a needle.  You can move the plunger in and out without too much difficulty.  When you pull the plunger out, the air above the plunger is at a slightly higher pressure, the air inside the syringe is at slightly lower pressure, and a flow is induced from above the plunger to into the syringe.  When you push the plunger, the opposite happens.

Now completely push the plunger in, and cover the tip with your finger.  Then pull on the plunger.  Now there's no path for the air to move into the syringe, and you can feel what 14.7psi feels like!

Comment: Okay that's kind of what I thought. There is still air behind it, and some flowing to fill it. And it's that air that still exerts a pressure such that in most conditions we can ignore it. That is what you are say Cort Ammon correct?

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz Yep.  That's the gist of it.  It gets more fun once you start moving fast, but at slow speeds, the effects become almost undetectable.

Comment: Thank you! It was a burning thought.

Comment: Cort Ammon, i have another question quickly. I think what confused me is this diagram of a car. https://www.buildyourownracecar.com/race-car-aerodynamics-basics-and-design/   It shows how there is vacuum in the rear. But that is not really true, it would be more accurate to say there is lower pressure. They are ignoring atmospheric pressure, treating 14.7 as zero, such then relative to the front there is vacuum. This is true as when you ride in the bed of a pickup, you can still breathe. Not like there isn't air and/or air pressure. Do you agree

Comment: @KevinCSpeltz Vacuum is a relative term.  Not even space is completely empty.  The vacuum is always is reference to some pressure (you'll often see the vacuum pulled measured in "gague" pressure, demonstrating that the measure is relative).  The picture you linked is imprecise, but the idea is that the car is indeed feeling a difference in air pressure between the front and the back, and the net result is drag.  The reason we focus on the vacuum is because *usually* that air pressure difference resolves itself, but at speed we can get regions with a ...

Comment: ... negative gauge pressure (i.e. pressure below free atmospheric pressure) which persist.  It doesn't take much to slow things down.  Consider that the rear surface of a truck is something like 6000 square inches.  Just going from 14.7psi to 14.6 is enough to generate 600 pounds of drag force!

Comment: That is what i was saying. Gauge pressure is the pressure minus the atmospheric pressure. So they are assuming we ignore the atmospheric 14.7 psi. Therefore if the front has some pressure, the rear would be relatively lower(hence vacuum). THis was helpful to see how pressure is still all around the car, but does change at speed. http://www.gcdataconcepts.com/carairflow.html